# shopify_auth multi store session handling

Tags: python, django, shopify

I am using Django with the shopify_auth package to connect with Shopify.

Does anyone have any examples of how to handle multi store sessions/connections?

So far, I am thinking of modifying shopify_auth's `@login_required` decorator with the following, but am unsure if I will miss anything with this:

In shopify_auth/decortaors.py:

```
def login_required(f, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            # Extract the Shopify-specific authentication parameters from the current request.
            new_request_d = [ ... get request.GET params ('shop', etc.) ... ]

            # Compare current active request.user with new reqeust.GET's 'shop'
            if request.user != new_request_d['shop']:
                [ ...  do something to change session to the other shop ...]
                [ ... redirect as necessary .... ]

            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the shopify_auth module their is an [unresolved issue about this](https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-auth/issues/5).

It hints at [using the ruby implementation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/697028001f71cf52e47d93749de426a0b3d7cf7d/lib/shopify_app/login_protection.rb#L27-L31).

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue in the apps I work on by creating a custom modified `SessionMiddleware` that creates and handles separate session cookies per store, and associates requests to their respective shop via (in the following order of precedence):

1. Request headers
2. URL parameters
3. Referrer

I unfortunately can't share the exact implementation due to closed-source agreements/restrictions, however I hope this leads you in the right direction.

**Make sure that you still include other security middleware (`CsrfViewMiddleware`, `AuthenticationMiddleware`, `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware`,
`SecurityMiddleware`) so the user can't spoof your system.**

The advantage to this rather than logging the user out is that if you're loading anything via AJAX, going back and forth between tabs of different app installs will always work, and you won't have to worry about implementing weird redirect logic to handle those errors.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to implement something like this previously but was getting stuck. I like this approach better as I think it sounds more seamless to the user. I will give it another try...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to swing back to implement this (as I have been working on other features). I am wondering if you would have time to take on a small job to create this custom session middleware for me?

Comment: My Skype is in my profile, feel free to get in touch

Answer (score 0):

Every request from Shopify comes with the shop domain. Your current session is set to a shop domain. Compare the two. If they differ, clear the old session, and auth a new one with the different incoming shop domain. Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: How do I access the new requests shop domain?

Comment: it is handed to you on a platter in the request as the parameter shop.

Comment: I can see 'shop' as a `request.GET` parameter only when it is passed as query string params. Sometimes it doesn't get passed though. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example (specific to the Python Shopify API that I am asking about)? I can see `x-shopid':  1231245` in my response, but cannot see anything else to do with "shop"...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, PHP, Ruby or any other scripting language. When you inspect your Request, the Shopify domain name (a good primary key as it never changes) is handed to you as a parameter. You use that to decide who is knocking at the door.
If you don't see it, then where is the request coming from? You? If you, then be sure to add it. Note that webhooks, carrier shipping requests and App Proxy calls instead use the header to embed that.